# How to make an App locker in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I would like to know if it is possible and how (where can I find documentation) to make an App locker for Windows Phone 8.1 in C#.

This App locker should:

1. get a list of all installed apps on the phone. 
   For this I found [InstallationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.phone.management.deployment.installationmanager.aspx) class and [FindPackages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj207250.aspx) method.But this method requires the ID_CAP_OEM_DEPLOYMENT capability and is not intended to be used directly from your code. So how to use it?
2. set a lock on a selected app
3. determine when a selected app is lunched and start another app written by me for authentication and only if the authentication is successful display the originally lunched app

Comment: The way this question is written, its both too broad, and appears to be asking for a software recommendation, both of which are off topic for SO.  Please update your question with code you've written and the error you're having with it.

Comment: This kind of application is not possible on Windows Phone due to the application sandboxing restrictions.

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking it is not possible but I needed a confirmation from somebody who maybe knows it for sure